# XCode 7 beta 4 - dmg image not recognized

Tags: xcode

XCode 7 beta 3 was working fine on OS X 10.11 beta earlier today. I went to install beta 4 and got this error. I don't see any work around.

> The following disk images couldn't be opened. Image:
>   Xcode_7_beta_4.dmg. Reason: image not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

I had to restart and re-download the program several times before it worked.